# feedback linearization for a quadrotor

Tags: mobile-robot, control, quadcopter

I am trying to develop a controller for a quadrotor using dynamic feedback linearization technique, but I am not sure I am doing thigs correctly. I know that for designing such controller I have to keep derivating until I see the input and it appears in a nonsingular way.

In my case, if I do this for example just for the $z$ coordinate I obtain that if I derivate two times I see the input in the expression of the second derivative, so after derivating two times I have:

$\ddot{z} = -cos(\theta )cos(\varphi )\frac{T}{m}+g$

where we can see that the thrust  $T$  appears. Now we can derive a control law using a dynamic controller of the form :

$J(\xi ,\zeta )^{-1}(-l(\xi ,\zeta)+v)$

where $\zeta = \begin{pmatrix} 
T\\ \dot{T}
\end{pmatrix}$, and I have understand well, we have do design such controller such that $\ddot{z} = v$ .

Now, if I apply this to the quadrotor, I obtain:

$T = \frac{m(g-\ddot{z}))}{cos(\theta )cos(\gamma )}$

where  $\ddot{z} = \ddot{z_{d}} -K_{d}(\dot{z_{d}} - \dot{z}) - K_{p}(z_{d}-z)$ and with $z_{d}$ as desired value for the $z$.

The problem is that it looks too much as a PID controller to me, so I don't see the difference between the two types of controller.

[EDIT] moreover, what are the benefits of using feedback linearization and what is the difference between this tecnhnique and using backstepping or PID controllers?

Can somebody please help me? Thank's in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "the two types of controller"? You mean feedback linearization (or input-output linearization) and PID? Namely [feedback linearization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feedback_linearization) alone isn't a full control law yet, but only your equation for $T$ with $\ddot{z}$ set equal to some to be determined new virtual input.

Comment: yes, by two controllers i meant feedback linearization and PID, but if I can' t derive a controller with feedback linearization I have some doubts on why is it used to control a quadrotor. I have understood that it is used beacause the quadrotor equations of motion are non-linear, but why is it present and is it not just used just backstepping? So what is the point of using feedback linearization and what are its benefits? I have a bit of confusion on this topic.